# Define string array in winrt resources

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In android we can create array of string in resource file. I don't have that code but it is something like this:

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
```

In c#, universal application (winrt) how can I save array in my resource file?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340%28v=vs.110%29.aspx first google result

Comment: Didn't understand that, Resource file has a GUI to enter text.

Comment: like this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx
 how to enter in this.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by having something like this in our resx/resw files:

```
<data name="StringArray_0" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>String in Array at position 0</value>
</data>
<data name="StringArray_1" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>String in Array at position 1</value>
</data>
<data name="StringArray_2" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>String in Array at position 2</value>
</data>
```

Then fetching the localized values by name "StringArray_" + index;

Comment: Change in resource file will require change in code also. I want to put array strings in combo box so that if i want to increase or decrease combo box data I dont have to change my code.